How to solve Blender only saving .blend1 files?
I accidentally opened a .blend1 file and set it to be opened by Blender always and since then, blender got rid of the original blender files and only saves .blend1 files, moreover, now every time I open a project, the command prompt tab remains, and doesn't close once the software is established as it used to, and I can't close it because then it closes Blender. It (the command prompt tab) also says this:  I use Windows 11. What could I do about it?

Aren't the original .blend files still in the same directory as the .blend1 files? If you open a .blend1 file you need to do File->Save As and not File->Save to get it saved as a .blend file again. When doing File->Save As Blender will append .blend to even a .blend1 file. You can edit the file name before clicking Save As. Once you are opening a .blend file again the terminal window won't open.

If you accidentally assigned Blender to .blend1 and do not want to be able to open it with a double-click, you can change this in the registry (keywords: "default app for file type windows 11"). Have a look here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-default-app/a425e784-0e48-4fa5-93e8-c7f08b47c324. I don't think that this is the reason for the opened system console/command prompt tab. You can hide and show it with the main menu Window > Toggle System Console

@Blunder FYI, if one has .blend1 files assigned to Blender and they click on the file to open it, at least in Windows 11, it is the Windows Terminal opening along with the file, not the Blender System Console. If they do a File->Open from inside Blender on a .blend1 file, the Windows Terminal doesn't open. In the case where it is the Windows Terminal that opened, if you close it, Blender closes.
